# Why is Docker able to save files to the source-directory?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, filesystems

I don't really know if this even classifies as a problem, but it somehow surprised me, since I thought that Docker containers run in sandboxed enviroments.

I have a running docker-container that includes a django-rest server.
When making the appropiate requests from the frontend (that's also served through a seperate NGINX-container in the same docker network) the request successfully triggers the response of the django server that includes writing the contents of the requests to a text-file.

Now, the path to the text file points to a subdirectory in the folder where the script itself is located.
But now the problem: the file is saved in the directory on the host-machine itself and (to my knowledge) not in the container.

Now is that something that docker is capable of doing or am I just not aware that django itself (which is running in the WSGI development server mind you) writes the file to the host machine.

```py
now = datetime.now()
timestamp = datetime.timestamp(now)

polygon = json.loads(data['polygon'])
string = ''
for key in polygon:
    string += f'{key}={polygon[key]}\r\n'

with open(f"./path/to/images/image_{timestamp}.txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write(string)
return 200
```

Is there something I am missing or something I do not understand about docker or django yet?

Comment: I think you should provide the examples of `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose.yml`. Perhaps you use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/), and it can mount host-directory to container-directory. In this case you have expected behavior.

Comment: I indeed use volumes. If it's expected behaviour for this case, then that explains it.